# Button to the same view ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, view

I am new to iPhone programming.

I have an app made with Storyboard having multiple views. In that couple of views are same, all having 5 statics buttons in the bottom of my app. I want to code all the buttons to go to the same view when they clicked. What is the best method?

I've been creating one class for one button and I'm trying write code to go to the view after click. I found only this code below but in this case I have to put segue on all views where buttons are

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier" sender:sender];  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonA;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonB;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [self.buttonA addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self.buttonB addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic behavior in your views you may need to implement a parent `UIViewController` in which you will put your `IBAction`:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
     UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;
     UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

     UIViewController *nextViewController = nil;
     switch (b.tag){
         case 0:
             nextViewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController0"];
             break;         
         // load the appropriate viewController according to button tag
         default:
             break;
      }

      if (nextViewController){
           [self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier" sender:sender];  
      }         
}
```

And I recommend you to take a look at [UITabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/) which could be the controller you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think everything you want just an `UITabViewController`.

If you want fixed 5 buttons at bottom all the time, UITabViewController could fulfill your requirement.

If you just want to add the same event for each button, you can refer this image:
[image]

you can just connect event and target code.